# Modify Asp gridview boundfield

Tags: asp.net, gridview, text, boundfield

I want to add some text to a boundfield build in the code behind without writing any code in the code behind.

example
I receive "overflow" in a specific field, and i'd like to display "stack overflow" and if i receive "house" i want to display "stack house"

is there a property to put text behind or after whatever comes in the boundfield ?

Comment: If your placement is conditional, it's likely you're going to end up putting something in the code behind anyway unless you keep your conditions extremely simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom column.

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyColumn">
    <ItemTemplate> 
         stack <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("myField")%>" />
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: could i databind it ? how would i do it ?

Comment: what would exactly be this myfield ?

Comment: Replace your `<asp:BoundField>` with the above code. `myField` is the name of the column in your datatable.

Answer (score 1):

notice

**HtmlEncode=false**

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="yourColumn" HeaderText="Your Header" DataFormatString="{0} overflow" HtmlEncode="false" SortExpression="GenCommission" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use item template?

```
// instead of 
<asP:BoundField DataField="FieldName" />

// use
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    prefix <%# Eval("FieldName") %> suffix
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: could i databind it ? this way wouldn't i need two columns ?

Comment: No, this should work as you suggested, the output would end up being stack overflow if overflow was the FieldsName